# Trigger event from an approuter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I created an application and it worked fine, most of the functionality is just the application reacting to different events.  I would like to implement a router so that users would be able to show their search results with other users etc.  The problem is the router appears to be set up correctly, as when i use it to append things directly to the body everything works as expected.  When I try to use the router to trigger events though nothing happens, any help would be greatly appreciated.  It is worth mentioning I suppose that this is not the complete code but just the parts that seemed relevant to the issue I am experiencing.

```
IEG = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

IEG.addRegions({
searchBox: '#searchBox',
resultBox: '#resultBox',
modalBox: '#modalBox',
recipientBox: '#recipientBox',
confirmBox: '#confirmToggleActive'
});

IEG.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

IEG.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },

index: function () {
    IEG.vent.trigger("default");    ////TRIGGER EVENT DOES NOT WORK
    //$(document.body).append("Index route has been called..");
}
});

SearchBoxView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template: Handlebars.templates['search'],

events: {
    'click #addGroup': 'addGroup',
    'keyup #searchStr': 'evaluateSearch'
},

addGroup: function () {
    IEG.vent.trigger("addGroup");
},

clearValidationMsg: function () {
    $('#searchErrors').html("");
},

evaluateSearch: function (e) {
    console.log("keyup DO SOMETHING> ", e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {///press enter execute search
        var searchStr = $('#searchStr').val().trim();
        if (searchStr) {
            IEG.vent.trigger("searchGroups", searchStr);
        }
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {//backspace and delete keys
        var searchStr = $('#searchStr').val().trim();
        if (!searchStr) {//when searchbar is cleared show all groups
            IEG.vent.trigger("searchGroups", null)
        }
    }
},

validateEmail: function (searchStr) {
    return /^.+@.+\..+$/.test(address); 
}
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    IEG.start();

new IEG.Router;
Backbone.history.start();

IEG.vent.on("default", function () {
    var SBV = new SearchBoxView();
    IEG.searchBox.show(SBV);
    IEG.searchColl = new GroupEntries();
    IEG.searchColl.fetch({
        data: {
            cmd: 0, //search groups
            searchStr: null //if null show all groups
        },
        success: function (data) {
            searchResults = new SearchResultsView({ collection: IEG.searchColl });
            IEG.resultBox.show(searchResults);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your event listeners are defined *before* the event is triggered. Most likely, the event trigger is working fine, but your event listener is registered after the router has triggered the event and nothing happens...